# OpenGL ES - Too much work on main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opengl-es

I'm trying to render a 3D cube with different textures on each face (a dice), it works flawlessly when I only render the cube with one of the same image, but the cube doesn't even display and the following is thrown in the android monitor when I try to do the former:

Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

After some research I'm aware that I could run this "heavy processing" in its own thread but I'm lost as to how to go about it. I'm relatively new to OpenGL rendering so I don't know whether my code is super optimal either.

I'm thinking I should run the Dice3D.java in another thread? This is the only class that doesn't extend or implement anything and through a little research I have found the class needs to implement runnable?

Any help in making this work would be great, thanks in advance!

Here are my classes:

**OpenGLRenderer.java**

```
public class OpenGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private Context context;
    private Dice3D dice3D;

    public OpenGLRenderer(Context context, FrameLayout openGLLayout) {
        this.context = context;
        dice3D = new Dice3D(context);

        GLSurfaceView glView = new GLSurfaceView(context);
        glView.setRenderer(this);

        //put to welcome layout
        openGLLayout.addView(glView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,   FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }

    private float mCubeRotation;

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);  // Set color's clear-value to black
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);            // Set depth's clear-value to farthest
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);   // Enables depth-buffer for hidden surface removal
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);    // The type of depth testing to do
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);  // nice perspective view
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);   // Enable smooth shading of color
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);      // Disable dithering for better performance

        // Setup Texture, each time the surface is created (NEW)
        dice3D.loadTexture(gl);             // Load images into textures (NEW)
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);  // Enable texture (NEW)
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);
        gl.glRotatef(mCubeRotation, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        dice3D.draw(gl);
        mCubeRotation -= 0.15f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }
}
```

**Dice3D.java**

```
public class Dice3D {

    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer; // Buffer for vertex-array
    private FloatBuffer texBuffer;    // Buffer for texture-coords-array (NEW)

    private int numFaces = 6;
    private int[] imageFileIDs = {  // Image file IDs
            R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.two,
            R.drawable.three,
            R.drawable.four,
            R.drawable.five,
            R.drawable.six
    };
    private int[] textureIDs = new int[numFaces];
    private Bitmap[] bitmap = new Bitmap[numFaces];

    // Constructor - Set up the buffers
    public Dice3D(Context context) {
        // Setup vertex-array buffer. Vertices in float. An float has 4 bytes
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(12 * 4 * numFaces);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); // Use native byte order
        vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer(); // Convert from byte to float

        for (int face = 0; face < numFaces; face++) {
            bitmap[face] = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getResources().openRawResource(imageFileIDs[face]));

            float[] vertices = { // Vertices for a face
                    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // 0. left-bottom-front
                    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // 1. right-bottom-front
                    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
                    1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f   // 3. right-top-front
            };
            vertexBuffer.put(vertices);  // Populate
        }
        vertexBuffer.position(0);    // Rewind

        float[] texCoords = { // Texture coords for the above face (NEW)
                0.0f, 1.0f,  // A. left-bottom (NEW)
                1.0f, 1.0f,  // B. right-bottom (NEW)
                0.0f, 0.0f,  // C. left-top (NEW)
                1.0f, 0.0f   // D. right-top (NEW)
        };

        // Setup texture-coords-array buffer, in float. An float has 4 bytes (NEW)
        ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texCoords.length * 4 * numFaces);
        tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        texBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer();
        for (int face = 0; face < numFaces; face++) {
            texBuffer.put(texCoords);
        }
        texBuffer.position(0);
    }

    // Draw the shape
    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);    // Front face in counter-clockwise orientation
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); // Enable cull face
        gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);    // Cull the back face (don't display)

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);  // Enable texture-coords-array (NEW)
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texBuffer); // Define texture-coords buffer (NEW)

        // front
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        // left
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(270.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        // back
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(180.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        // right
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(90.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        // top
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(270.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        // bottom
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(90.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);  // Disable texture-coords-array
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    }

    // Load an image into GL texture
    public void loadTexture(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glGenTextures(6, textureIDs, 0); // Generate texture-ID array for 6 IDs

        // Generate OpenGL texture images
        for (int face = 0; face < numFaces; face++) {
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[face]);
            // Build Texture from loaded bitmap for the currently-bind texture ID
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap[face], 0);
            bitmap[face].recycle();
        }
    }

}
```

**and finally my activity Welcome.java**

```
public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout l1,l2;
    public Button btnsub;
    Animation uptodown,downtoup;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        FrameLayout openGLLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1);

        //creates an openGL surface and renders it to the framelayout in the activity layout
        OpenGLRenderer gl3DView = new OpenGLRenderer(this, openGLLayout);


        btnsub = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonsub);
        btnsub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent test = new Intent(Welcome.this,DiceGame.class);
                startActivity(test);
            }
        });
        l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l1);
        l2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l2);
        uptodown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.uptodown);
        downtoup = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.downtoup);
        l1.setAnimation(uptodown);
        l2.setAnimation(downtoup);

    }
}
```

Comment: So, you've posted the code that works flawlessly using a single texture? Might be useful to post the code that doesn't work too.

Comment: Nope, this is the code that is rendering 6 different textures one on each face of the cube. When the code in this post is ran in the emulator, the cube doesn't display, but does when I load the same texture across all 6 faces

Comment: I think you need to be binding a texture (gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[face_you_want_to_draw]);
) before you draw each face.

Comment: Would that be in the onDrawFrame method or would it have to be moved around in the Dice3D class? thanks for your help btw

Comment: To use 6 different textures you would put a glBindTexture call before each of the 6 calls to glDrawArrays.

Comment: Still doesn't work - getting the same message Too much work on main thread.

Comment: // bottom
        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(90.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[5]);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        gl.glPopMatrix();

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance:

1) Learn OpenGL ES 2.0 and use shaders; it's a much cleaner API with a lot less messing about needed in the application and/or in the driver stack. All of the new APIs are shader-based, so this is a good thing to learn. I wouldn't consider using OpenGL ES 1.x for any new projects as it's a dead-end from a technology point of view.

(2) Once using OpenGL ES 2.0 or newer the use buffer objects for storing vertex data, and upload the data at the start of the application, nor per frame. It shouldn't really matter in this case (cube is very simple), but it's a good habit to get in to.

Comment: Thanks will look into it. Do you know why this particular code will not render the cube though?